# Acrobat Pro: PDF dimensions not exact

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, adobe-acrobat, dimensions, units

I'm wondering for a while now: When I export a document in InDesign and view the dimensions of the pdf in Acrobat Pro, the dimensions are a little off (like ~0.002 cm).

[image: acrobat dimensions]

Should be 29.7 x 21 cm. When I import the pdf in InDesign, the dimensions are correct. It doesnt matter if I export a print or screen/interactive version or if I include bleed in the export settings.

My best guess is that there is an internal conversion error because indesign is using different units? Is there an option where I can select the unit system and fix this?

Comment: Pixels. Same thing happens in Photoshop, PS or Acrobat read the resolution (for example 200 pixel per inch) then it recalculate to milimetres. And because you cannot have half of pixel it's rounded up or down.

Answer (score 0):

All I found is some general preference (through the Edit menu on Windows, through the Acrobat menu on Mac OS) - seen screen shot.

Perhaps check if this makes a difference ? [image: screen capture]